# Get PID of the host script in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, process

I have a script (`run.sh`) which calls my application script. At a given time, I may have multiple `run.sh` running.

The general format of the run.sh script is,

```
#!/bin/bash
# Running DALTON JOB: Helix
dir=$(pwd)
    echo "-----------------------------------------------"
   export DALTON_TMPDIR=/mnt/raid0/scratch
    export OMP_NUM_THREADS=6
    source /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.0.098/linux/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
    source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64
    echo "//-------process started----------------------------//"

./application.sh  -mb 14550 input.mol output.out

echo "//-------process finished----------------------------//"
```

Is it possible to get the PID of the `application.sh` inside the `run.sh` script. 
(I found that `$$` gives the PID of the script itself.)

Also, I noticed that the PID of the application is always larger numerically than parent script but maybe its coincidence.

Comment: does `./application.sh` get run in the background? otherwise, it will have exited by the time run.sh could do anything with the PID.

Comment: `application.sh` runs in the background ( for ~3-4 hours) as a host process of `run.sh`.

Comment: Who needs to get whose PID? Does `application.sh` need to get the PID of the instance of `run.sh` that launched it? Or does `run.sh` need to get the PID of `application.sh`?

Comment: `run.sh` need to get the PID of `application.sh` . `run.sh` is the parent and `application.sh` was started by running `./run.sh`

Comment: Aside: the PID is assigned in increasing numerical order, so in general parents have a lower PID number than children. However, there is a point where the PID wrap. E.g., the maximum PID is 32768, so it is possible for a child process to have a lower PID number than a parent. (note: 32768 is an example and not necessarily the max value on a given system).

Comment: eliding the actual call to application.sh with "parameters" muddies the waters. show that it goes into the background, then I think this Q has a usable answer.

Comment: @JeffSchaller : I am not sure how to show that. Any suggestion to me for this.

Comment: does run.sh put a `&` at the end of the call to application.sh?

Comment: @JeffSchaller No, it does not.

Comment: I'm confused. You do not put it in the background; it runs for 3-4 hours, and then you get the "echo process finished"?  The application.sh has exited by that point. What PID do you want, and where?

Comment: Oh, I see your point. I think the idea about using the PID was wrong. I thought I could echo the PID (of `application.sh`) to a file, while it is running  using `run.sh`. But I see that it is contradictory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60130/discussion-between-ankit7540-and-jeff-schaller).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to see the PID of `application.sh` while it is running, then I would suggest explicitly putting it into the background, capturing the PID, then waiting for it to exit:

```
# ...
./application.sh  -mb 14550 input.mol output.out &
app_pid=$!
echo "The application pid is: $app_pid"
wait "$app_pid"
# ...
```

Comment: I would second this. '$!' captures the pid of the last executed (backgrounded) command which is the command in question.

Comment: I need a clarification. `wait "$app_pid"`  keeps the `run.sh` waiting till application.sh finishes right ??

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you may want a combination of something like `pstree -p` and `ps axjf` with some additional parsing.

Notice how the PID of `httpd` is `30469`, and every process that is a child of `httpd` has a `PPID` (parent process ID) of `30469`. The grandchildren of `httpd` will have the `PPID` of their parent process, which will have the `PPID` of the `httpd` process.

I didn't post the full output of either as they are rather large. Here's an example output from each:

```
user@host$ ps -axjf
PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
1     30469 30469 30469 ?           -1 Ss       0   0:46 /usr/sbin/httpd
30469 22410 22410 22410 ?           -1 Ssl      0   0:00  \_ PassengerWatchdog
22410 22413 22413 22410 ?           -1 Sl       0  23:06  |   \_ PassengerHelperAgent
22410 22418 22418 22410 ?           -1 Sl      99   0:01  |   \_ PassengerLoggingAgent
30469 22442 30469 30469 ?           -1 Sl      48   7:55  \_ (wsgi:pulp)
30469 22443 30469 30469 ?           -1 S       48   1:48  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
30469 22445 30469 30469 ?           -1 S       48   1:55  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
30469 22447 30469 30469 ?           -1 S       48   1:54  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd

user@host$ pstree -p
 ├─httpd(30469)─┬─PassengerWatchd(22410)─┬─PassengerHelper(22413)─┬─{PassengerHelpe}(22415)
        │              │                        │                        ├─{PassengerHelpe}(22416)
        │              │                        │                        ├─{PassengerHelpe}(22417)
        │              │                        │                        ├─{PassengerHelpe}(22420)
        │              │                        │                        ├─{PassengerHelpe}(22422)
        │              │                        │                        ├─{PassengerHelpe}(22423)
        │              │                        │                        ├─{PassengerHelpe}(29342)
```

Note if you know the parent process tree you can run `pstree -p <pid>`.

Answer (score 1):

To save the process ID of a utility, start it as an asynchronous process and save its PID in a variable, or use `$!` directly (it's the PID of the most recently started background process):

```
#!/bin/bash

export DALTON_TMPDIR=/mnt/raid0/scratch
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=6
source /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.0.098/linux/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64

printf 'Started at "%s"\n' "$(date)"

SECONDS=0
./application.sh -mb 14550 input.mol output.out &

app_pid="$!"

printf 'Application PID is %d\n' "$app_pid"

wait "$app_pid"

printf 'Ended at "%s"\n' "$(date)"
printf 'Run time was approximately %d minutes (%d seconds)\n' "$(( SECONDS/60 ))" "$SECONDS"
```

The PID of the application is `$app_pid`.

---

You say you have noticed that the PIDs of new processes are always larger than those of previous processes. This is nothing that you may rely on for two reasons:

1. There will be a PID allocation wrap-around once the maximum allowed PID has been allocated to a process, and old PIDs will start to be reused.  The next PID will be smaller, not larger, than the previous PID when the wrap-around happens (and new PIDs after that will skip numbers that are still in use as PIDs by running processes).
2. Some systems, like OpenBSD, use randomized PID allocation:

   ```
   $ for i in {1..5}; do bash -c 'echo $$'; done
   49915
   2152
   61168
   87739
   95187
   ```

---

As a side note, you may use `$PWD` rather than `$(pwd)` to get the current working directory.